# How to call a method from a dynamic template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, meteor-blaze

I'm building a settings page in Meteor which will include dynamic templates for the many categories of settings.

What I'm trying to do is have a method in my category template that will be called when I click the submit button on the parent template.

*settings.html*

```
<div>
  {{> Template.dynamic template=settings}}
  <div class="submit">
    <button>Save Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*settings.coffee*

```
Template.settings.events
    'click .submit button': ->
        dynamiclyLoadedTemplate.save()
```

*my-dynamic-template.coffee*

```
Template.dynamicTemplate.onCreated ->
    @save = ->
        # doSomething()
```

*my-other-dynamic-template.coffee*

```
Template.otherDynamicTemplate.onCreated ->
    @save = ->
        # doSomethingElse()
```

Is this possible?

Should I create these methods as window methods, instead of template methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code in your child template:

```
Template.childTemplate.onCreated ->

    settingsTemplate = this.parentTemplate(...) # ... = number of upstream levels
    settingsTemplate.child ?= []
    settingsTemplate.child.push this

    @save = ->
        console.log 'Save called'
```

So you can call the following code on the parent template:

```
Template.parentTemplate.events

    'click .submit button': ->
        console.log 'submit button clicked'

        instance = Template.instance()

        if instance.child?.length > 0
            for child in instance.child
                child.save?()
```

Comment: Yes, Gabriel, that's what I was trying to do!
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar pattern where I just attach the events to the parent template (the one that loads the dynamic template). The data context will be that of the parent but that's still better than attaching the methods to the *window* object especially since in my case the sub-templates all deal with the same type of object anyway.

In your case, first make the parent of your dynamic templates a template itself:

```
<template name="parent">
  <div>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=settings}}
    <div class="submit">
      <button>Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then just attach the event(s) to that parent:

```
Template.parent.events
    'click .submit button': ->
        save() // generic save function you've defined, for example in this file
```

This works well when the dynamically included templates have the same kind of object and usually similar DOM elements, at least those that you want to attach events to.

Comment: How do you attach events to the parent template? Can you override the event when one or the other dynamic template is rendered?

Comment: Modified my answer to show that. If you want to do template level overrides then attach those events and code to the lower level templates instead of cluttering up your generic code.

Comment: If you define save() as a generic method on parent template, how would you call sub-template specific actions when saving?

Comment: You'd have to override the actual event handler. Ex:`Template.child.events 'click .submit button': -> mySave()`

Comment: How can I override the event handler, if the '.submit button' is in parent template? Doing `Template.child.events 'click .submit button': -> mySave()` would not match anything on DOM

Comment: You're right - you'd have to put the button in the child templates instead. Then the handler in the parent template would be the *default* handler but if a child template had its own handler it would override.